# ASP.NET Webforms write output html for control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to create my own hierarchical navigation menu control without using standart ASP.NET controls. So, I want to control my html output and I found out that I can override Render method to write html into respose. Is it good place for this? Where in control creating lifecycle I should prepare data for my control?

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
    Response.Write("<b>hello</b>");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly the Render method that is the correct place to do this. But don't write it to the Response, write it to the provided as argument `HtmlTextWriter` instead.